# Query regarding failure of workflow in github for react application

Tags: reactjs

I was making workflow file for React App this is as below:

```
name: React App
on: [push]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Deploying to surge
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2-beta
        with:
          node-version: 12.18.2
      - name: Install React
        uses: npx create-react-app react-base-app
      - name: Start react
        uses: npm start
      - name: Install Surge
        run: npm install -g surge
      - name: Run surge
        run: surge ./ bootcamp_setup_ziakhan.surge.sh --token ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}
```

Now when I am running github actions it is showing following message:

```
The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/yaml_React.yml (Line: 14, Col: 15): Expected format {org}/{repo}[/path]@ref. Actual 'npx create-react-app react-base-app',Input string was not in a correct format.
```

Comment: Why are you trying to create a *new* app in the action?

Comment: Actually I want to deploy in the surge.

Comment: @jonrsharpe now it is showing this error after I make changes 
.github#L1
Process completed with exit code 1.

Answer (score 0):

Done this is the answer

name: React App
on: [push]
jobs:
build:
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
name: Deploying to surge
steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v2
- name: Install Node.js
uses: actions/setup-node@v2-beta
with:
node-version: 12.18.2
- name: Install Yarn
uses: borales/actions-yarn@v2.0.0
with:
cmd: install # will run `yarn install` command
- name: Build React
run: yarn build
- name: Install Surge
run: npm install --g surge
- name: Run surge
run: surge ./ build boundless-beast.surge.sh --token ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}